# How does one cancel Fraps loop-recording without recording?

Tags: recording, fraps

Fraps has an innovative feature that it calls loop recording. With this option turned on, Fraps will always be recording the last amount of time that you specify (in seconds with a usual, unspoken maximum of 90 seconds or 4 GB) in the settings.

To actually keep the footage that it's recording, one must press the record hotkey (default: F9) which will cause Fraps to start recording. Pressing the record hotkey again will cause all recording to stop. I want to know how to stop loop recording without starting recording, instead simply deleting the loop recording buffer.

Is there a way to do this? I'm thinking that it's possible with a script to kill the Fraps process, but I am hoping for something softer. I don't know if force quitting Fraps for this purpose would cause problems.